# Decrypt Lua byte code?

Tags: lua, bytecode, encryption

I'm encrypting my Lua code with this script.

```
local script = string.dump(
    function()
        local function h4x(strtbl)
            buffer=""
            for v in strtbl do
                buffer=buffer..strtbl[v]
            end
            return buffer
        end

        print("encrypted")

    end
)

buff=""
for v=1,string.len(script) do --Convert our string into a hex string.
    buff=buff..'\\'..string.byte(script,v)
end

file=io.open('encrypted.txt','w') --Output our bytecode into ascii format to encrypted.txt
file:write(buff)
file:flush()
file:close()
```

The output of encrypted.txt is like "00/12/46/4/2/6/4/62/". How do I decrypt bytecode?

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872861/lua-equivalent-to-python-dis

Comment: notice that string.len has been deprecated since Lua 5.1 . Use `#script` instead.

Answer (score 6):

This text is not encrypted. It's just Lua bytecode in hexadecimal.

Discussion of means of disassembling this bytecode into human-readable opcodes is in another question: [Lua equivalent to Python dis()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872861/lua-equivalent-to-python-dis)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously its printing out each BYTE as a value (which is decimal, even though its stated its converted to hex) delimited by a '/'.

All you need to do then is fill an array using the bytes you pull from the string, using `tonumber` to convert them back to their byte value. [this](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaCsv) will help with parsing the formatted output